# Zuora Quote: Line breaks not being printed on the generated PDF

Tags: quote-template, line-break, zuora

I have a formula field that is being used on the quote template for populating a certain legal section on the generated quote PDF. The formula field is using the `BR()` function to divide the text block into multiple paragraphs.

Instead of printing the new line, it is printing the HTML tag for the line break (that is, `<br>`) in the generated PDF.

Please suggest how I can represent a new line on the quote template for printing the line break on the PDF.

Comment: Have you checked Zuora support resources?

Comment: @DavidCheng Yes, I did reach out to them but they weren't much help. But, anyway, I was able to identify the issue and, also, got the workaround for it.

Comment: What was your solution?  I've voted to re-open your question so you can post your own answer.

Comment: @DavidCheng Needs more votes... I'll answer once the question opens :)

Comment: I've reopened this question to allow it to be answered. I do want to reiterate that that question was presumably closed because of the specific reference to Zuora. Zuora is _not_ on topic at SFSE.

Comment: @DavidReed Makes sense... Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for it using **Custom Labels**.

The `BR()` function is used to insert a line break between strings of text. But in our case, rather than putting the line break, the HTML tag `<br>` was being printed in the generated PDF.

This seems to be a known issue that generally comes up in cases of Flows and Processes.

As a workaround, I created a Custom Label named `New_Line` and used it in the concerned formula fields. Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image: New Line Custom Label]

The label needs to have the dummy starting and ending characters (in my case, `<` and `>`) because all leading and trailing whitespaces get removed. So, the value of this custom label will be as follows.

```
<
>
```

This custom label can then be used in a formula field as follows.

```
"<some string>" & MID($Label.New_Line,2,1) & "<another string>"
```

Once I updated the concerned formula fields, the generated PDFs had the desired line breaks.